# Sink like a stone

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

***Sinking like a stone***

I have seen this idiom for the first time today. [thefreedictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sink+like+a+stone) says it means "*To fail completely*"; is it common to use it in daily conversation and why in the example below it is written, *"England sink.."* and not *"England sinks.."*. Can we use both forms in such structure?

> I MAY be going against the grain of public opinion, but I sincerely
>   hope England sink like a stone at the European Championships.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is fairly common. It's *hope England sink* because in British English the names of sports teams can be treated as plurals.